# What is a clean/fast way of calling methods with complex object params in another classloader?

Tags: java, classloader

We're working on a situation where we can run processing through different versions of our processor. We load each version in a different classloader. But the API we need to call uses our own classes that may change over different versions. So a class might have a different definition in the caller classloader as the one in the callee classloader.

I'm looking for a high performance way of handling this situation. My understanding is that object serialization can be a significant performance hit, and if the class has changed enough, it won't work at all.

Restriction: we cannot modify the code that we're wanting to call. We could possibly include new code inside the callee classloader, but we cannot modify the code that we're trying to run.

Comment: What do you mean by "caller classloader" and "callee classloader"? Is the program running in a single JVM or is it distributed?

Comment: Single JVM. Caller classloader is the code that wants to call into the other classloader. Callee is the one holding the code that is to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You could use interfaces or abstract classes that are loaded by the system class loader and that are implemented by your different processor versions. Now when you load your processor implementations in their own custom class loaders they will still *link* against the interfaces from the system class loader and thus all implement the same intrerfaces. The result is as fast as it gets in Java but you would need to have interfaces that remain stable accross your different versions.

Comment: Ah, I'll add this detail: that won't work because the previous version code cannot be touched. So, we can't go modify previous version code to implement interfaces or abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this for the last days, its one interesting problem.

While I don't think it is possible at all to do exactly what you want I came up with a bit complex solution but it could help you, I hope.

You start a VM with the old version of your classes, providing RMI methods to it. Then from your caller Classloader you start RMI connectios to that other VM to get Datasets from the old ones that are NOT Instances of the classes there but Standart Java Objects (like a Map).
Then you transfer that Map on the Caller site into an instance of the version you need it.

That way you don't have conflicting versions of a class within a single VM.

If needed I can provide you some example code to demonstrate what I mean, but there is a lot of implementation ahead of you :)

As for the performance part: If you construct the interfaces of the communicating RMI Parts tight enough the RMI Overhead won't cost you much and in every VM there are no large serialization problems.

Have fun (and if you care, leave a note on how it turned out)

Comment: You can do the same thing you describe without RMI. It's the standard Java serialization (which is supposedly rather slow, isn't it?) that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @tautree No. The standard serialization loads and writes every piece of information from a given class with the limits that you cannot control much on what is done while doing so. Having it run in different VMs gives you a lot more power on what part is doing where and you can optimize it for being fast for any single given action. If you want to load/write all pieces of a class then serialization is a good approach. At this point its impossible to help you any further without knowing a lot more details about your problem, unfortunately. If the information does not fit here, write me an email.